# how can you get the app ID for my iPhone application before I submit it to Apple?

Tags: iphone, ipad, appirater

I am using Appirater for my iPhone application and it requires me to put in the APPIRATER_APP_ID which is described as the `Apple generated software id`. How do I get this ID while my app is still under development?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You basically create the app in [iTunesConnect](https://itunesconnect.apple.com) and then you get its Apple ID, which consists of a number. You will see this full ID once you have completed registering your app.

So go to iTunesConnect, select *Manage Your Apps* and then *Add your app* using the button at the top or select an existing app. Under *App Information* there is the *apple ID* given.

You can then later upload your app to iTunesConnect.