# How to alert for rating in iphone app?

Tags: iphone, rating

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you prompt the user to rate your iphone app without waiting for them to delete the app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2015470/how-do-you-prompt-the-user-to-rate-your-iphone-app-without-waiting-for-them-to-d)

how to put rating alert to application when we launch the application and show to get rating alert box to get rating 
Please give me example i am fresher developer

Comment: I saw that question but i can't find solution

Comment: ??? It's all in there - look at Appirater, that's the whole code you need.

Comment: It's very annoying when apps do this. I'd suggest _not_ doing askig for review. As a bonus that's even easier to implement ;)

Comment: How to get APPIRATER APP_ID ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add Appirater

you can download it from here

https://github.com/arashpayan/appirater/

Answer (score 3):

As TheEye mentioned, you have to use [Appirater](https://github.com/arashpayan/appirater/)

Comment: can this file work in simulator ?

Comment: No! There is no App Store on the simulator.

Comment: No, usually it takes it to AppStore. Since AppStore is not present in simulator, it won't work in simulator.

Comment: i check app in device but i can't get alert box

Comment: How to get APPIRATER APP_ID ?

Comment: Please see this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5060680/how-can-you-get-the-app-id-for-my-iphone-application-before-i-submit-it-to-apple)